# Get the first element in the array of objects in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

I want to get the 'appName' from the array of objects

I'm using 'react-native-android-installed-apps' to get a list of all the apps in the device. I've managed to get the apps in an object but I am failing to access the 'appName' in the from the object of arrays

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import RNAndroidInstalledApps from 'react-native-android-installed-apps';

class App extends Component {
    check() {
        names = {
            apps: null
        };
        RNAndroidInstalledApps.getApps()
            .then(apps => {
                names.apps = apps
            });

        console.log(names);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
                {this.check()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

What I want from the object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNdP2.jpg

I expect to get 'appName' from the array of objects and then use flat list to display all the apps

Comment: Can you tell me what you have and what's the issue?

Comment: You should learn about Promise to understand this problem correctly.
Dacre Denny's answer is correct. But he didn't explain about your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The `apps` data returned from `RNAndroidInstalledApps.getApps()` is an `Array` which means you can access the first app name by the following:

```
const firstAppItem = apps[0];
const firstAppName = firstAppItem.appName;
```

To display this, you'll need to update your component to ensure that it is re-rendered when the app data becomes available (ie after the `.then()` handler is called).

The following changes would display the name of the first app returned from `RNAndroidInstalledApps.getApps()`:

```
class App extends Component {

    /* Define state of app component */
    state = { firstAppName : "Loading" };

    componentDidMount() {
        /* When component first mounts/starts, run check() once */
        this.check();
    }

    check() {

        RNAndroidInstalledApps.getApps()
            .then(apps => {

                if(apps.length > 0) {

                    /* Get first item from apps array */
                    const firstApp = apps[0];

                    /* Set component state with first app name */
                    this.setState({ firstAppName : firstApp.appName });
                }
                else {

                    /* If no apps returned, display default message */
                    this.setState({ firstAppName : 'No app name found' });
                }                    
            });
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
                { this.state.firstAppName }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

#### Update

To list all app names:

```
class App extends Component {

    state = { appNames : [] };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.check();
    }

    check() {

        RNAndroidInstalledApps.getApps()
            .then(apps => {                       
                this.setState({ 
                    appNames : apps.map(app => app.appName) 
                });               
            });
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
                { 
                    this.state.appNames.map(appName => 
                    <Text>{ appName }</Text>) 
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That is correct but what if we want to loop through the array of objects and get all the 'appName' in an array? How will we modify the code

Comment: @MohammadHasnainAli just added an update - does that help?